# Why is Mathematica so slow when tables reach a certain length?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

So Here is an example:
I have a table full of numbers:

```
foo = Table[Table[RandomComplex[], {i, 1000}], {j, 8192}];
```

Now I want to do things with some elements of this table:

```
Table[Abs[foo[[1, 21]] - foo[[1, -20]]], {249}];
```

And this runs fine and takes about 0 seconds to evaluate. But I want to do more:

```
Table[Abs[foo[[1, 21]] - foo[[1, -20]]], {250}];
```

And suddenly it takes about 3 seconds. Why whould that be when I just increased the . But I want to do even more:

```
Table[RandomComplex[]*Table[Abs[foo[[1, 21]] - foo[[1, -20]]], {250}], {249}];
```

And this still takes about 3 seconds. But now I want to take it one step further:

```
Table[RandomComplex[]*Table[Abs[foo[[1, 21]] - foo[[1, -20]]], {250}], {250}];
```

And this takes forever and I get a CPU load of 60% on my quadcore. As if something is being evaluated in parallel even though I did not ask for it. And it takes 1001 seconds to evaluate. How is this possible and why is there a magic number 250 involved? It there a way to solve this issue without chopping my data into chunks of size<250 before processing?

Does anyone have the same issue or can recreate this problem on their system? Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Perhaps `SystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> "TableCompileLength"]`?

Comment: This looks like the same MSE issue that was reported as a bug several days ago.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Perhaps this:

```
WithCleanup[
 SetSystemOptions[
  "CompileOptions" -> "TableCompileLength" -> Infinity],
 Table[Abs[foo[[1, 21]] - foo[[1, -20]]], {2500}]; // AbsoluteTiming,
 SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> "TableCompileLength" -> 250]
 ]

(*  {0.006308, Null}  *)
```

Pre V12.2, use `` WithCleanup = Internal`WithLocalSettings ``.

Alternatively, `Compile` your `Table`:

```
Compile[{{foo, _Complex, 2}},
    Table[
     RandomComplex[]*
      Table[Abs[foo[[1, 21]] - foo[[1, -20]]], {250}], {250}]
    ][foo]; // AbsoluteTiming

(*  {0.014384, Null}  *)
```

Comment: Perfect. This works just fine. Is it potentially unsafe to always set `SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> "TableCompileLength" -> Infinity]` ? Also is there any documentation on this?

Comment: @WalterLarsLee  It should be fairly safe. Often you want a medium-low setting because `Compile` normally speeds things up. Setting it to `Infinity` might slow down a lot of other things. I imagine (don't know for sure) that in your case `foo` is getting copied into the compiled code when the limit is low, and that takes time to copy and compile. It seems to be a one-time expense and lengthening the table does not lengthen the running time much. It might pay off to leave the limit low if you have a high number of iterations, since with the compiled function, each iteration might be faster.

Answer (score 5):

With any version we can use

```
foo = Table[Table[RandomComplex[], {i, 1000}], {j, 8192}];

 
   With[{s1 = {250}, s2 = {250}, 
     q = Abs[foo[[1, 21]] - foo[[1, -20]]]}, 
    Table[RandomComplex[]*Table[q, s1], s2]]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[]= {0.0010452, Null}
```

In more general case it takes about {0.144313, Null}

```
f[i_, j_] := Abs[foo[[i, 21]] - foo[[j, -20]]]
With[{s1 = {i, 250}, s2 = {j, 250}}, 
   Table[RandomComplex[]*Table[f[i, j], s1], s2]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

Comment: very interesting. But it seems to me that this only works because it explicitly shifts the calculation `Abs[foo[[1, 21]] - foo[[1, -20]]]` outside of the Table. eventually I would like to use an iterator such that `q` would become something like `q[i_,j_]` and that seems to break this solution.

Comment: @WalterLarsLee Could you define expression `q[i,j] ` to check what actually break?