# Why does this small change make execution 30,000x slower?

Tags: performance-tuning

Recently, when using Mathematica to process some triangle meshes, I noticed an unusual slowdown when processing a large mesh.

```
(* import the vertex coordinates and triangle-element connectivity *)
v = Partition[BinaryReadList["/path/to/vertices.bin", "Real32"], 3];
e = Partition[BinaryReadList["/path/to/triangles.bin", "UnsignedInteger64"], 3] + 1;

(* generate random numbers for testing *)
n = 20000000;
v = Partition[RandomReal[1, 3 n], 3];
e = Partition[RandomInteger[n - 1, 3 n], 3] + 1;

(* compute the centroids of the first 250 triangles *)
centroids = Table[Mean[v[[e[[i]]]]], {i, 1, 250}];

(* other other steps in the analysis *)
...
```

For some reason, that centroid calculation seemed to take a really long time. If I measure with `AbsoluteTiming[]` I see

```
Table[Mean[v[[e[[i]]]]], {i, 1, 250}]; // AbsoluteTiming
35.5656
```

Curiously, if I only want to compute the first 249 centroids, the calculation finishes quickly

```
Table[Mean[v[[e[[i]]]]], {i, 1, 249}]; // AbsoluteTiming
0.001143
```

So, it must be the case that element 250 is unusual in some way, causing the slowdown. How long does it take to calculate that centroid in isolation?

```
Mean[v[[e[[250]]]]] // AbsoluteTiming
0.000039
```

Hmm, no, that finishes instantly as well. What could be causing this 30,000x slowdown?

---

For reference, the sizes of the relevant mesh data are given below:

```
Dimensions[v]
{210848942, 3}
--------
Dimensions[e]
{117676276, 3}
```

Times were measured on an Ubuntu 22.04 machine running Mathematica 13.3.0. I have also just updated to Mathematica 14.0.0, and the problem still persists.

Comment: Is it same slow with `Mean[v[[#]]] & /@ e[[1 ;; 250]]`?

Comment: Yes, just as slow. The long 30s runtime is consistent, too. Rerunning that cell and/or restarting the kernel don't make a difference.

Comment: It is hard to tell what is going on without the data.

Comment: With `Table` you can never know, because it may run some jit compilation at high trip count. The critical number of elements for switching that behavior is 250. (At least I think I saw this number pop up somewhere.) But this is a task that is quicker done without `Table` by just `Total[Partition[(1/3 v)[[Flatten[e]]], 3], {2}]`.

Comment: That said, 30 seconds is way above what anybody would expect from jit compilation.

Comment: You might want to send full code to replicate this to Tech Support.

Comment: Try SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> {"SumCompileLength" -> Infinity, "ArrayCompileLength" -> Infinity, "ProductCompileLength" -> Infinity}];

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, I added a code to the question to generate random numbers (of "similar" dimensions), and I can now [reproduce this issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIto6.png) (`"13.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 3, 2023)"`). Also, @Vaclav's solution doesn't seem to help ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is mathematica so slow when tables reach a certain length](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/239828/why-is-mathematica-so-slow-when-tables-reach-a-certain-length) @VaclavKotesovec, out of the three, you just missed the critical one, namely `"TableCompileLength" -> Infinity`, which indeed helps! :)

Comment: @Domen: yes, OK.

Comment: I can confirm that setting several of these XXXCompileLength parameters to infinity addresses the issue, but it still seems like a bug in the compilation mechanism. In C/C++, it takes a fraction of a millisecond to compile the function being mapped over the list.

Comment: Domen or Vaclav, could you write your response as an answer so that I can accept it? Also, what is the appropriate way to report this compilation performance bug to Wolfram?

Comment: @smish, the answer was provided in the other question (hence this one was closed). However, I don't understand your other comment. Have you read that other question that has some explanations and solutions (e.g. using `Compile`)?

Comment: For reporting an issue there is [this link](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/). In this case I have sent the issue to some people in-house who might know more about why it gets so slow, or whether there might be a simple way to improve on the automatic behavior at our end. I am leaving it to the experts to decide whether this gets a bug report. Thanks @domen for adding the code to reproduce-- I found it quite helpful in tracking the bottlenecks.